# using the data only AFTER useEffect

Tags: javascript, use-effect

I have a react component (written with Typescript) as below.

In this component, I try to read the excel in which I have the data & then use the data for rendering the component

Since the data is not read before the `useEffect` is run, the menuData is initialized as a `null`.

Reading the data works fine & I have no error with menuData.

However, the line `let meals = [...new Set(menuData.map((item: menuItem) => item.Meal))];` is throwing the error `TypeError: menuData is undefined`. I think this is because this line is executed when the menuData is still `undefined` (before the useEffect runs).

How to overcome this error? In other words, how to run `let meals = [...new Set(menuData.map((item: menuItem) => item.Meal))];` AFTER useEffect has run?

I would like to keep this line outside of useEffect because there are many more array functions (map, filter...etc) that need to be performed on menuData array of objects.

```
export const CategoryItems = ({ toggled }: CategoryItemsProps) => {
  
const [menuData, setMenuData] = useState<menuData | undefined>(undefined);

   /*Code to read the excel with menu items once the page is loaded.
  The sheet will be read only once*/
  useEffect(() => {
    let url = "data.xlsx";
........
....
.....
      setMenuData(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { raw: true }));

  }, []);

 let meals = [...new Set(menuData.map((item: menuItem) => item.Meal))];

  return (
    <div className={`category-items ${toggled ? "theme-dark" : "theme-light"}`}>
.
.
.
    //additional code to render the component based on the variable `meals`
.
.
.
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: why not just initialize the state as an empty array already? `const [menuData, setMenuData] = useState<menuData>([]);`

Comment: I assume your useEffect is async, so you can't make it run after it, because it's something that's going to happen in the future.  But what you can do is run it on the second render that setMenuData will fire..  You could make menuData initially empty, but I personally like the early return null option, why even bother processing JSX if's it not in a state to be rendered.  So before your `let meals`,  just do `if (!menuData) return null;`,  you can of course replace the `null` with some form of loading indicator, this will depend on how long your useEffect takes if this is something you do.

Comment: @PedroFeltrin this works! If you want to put this as an answer. I will up-Vote it.

Comment: @Keith I am not sure if I completely understand your suggestion. Where should I add `if (!menuData) return null`? Within `useEffect`?

Comment: @moys  No just put it before your `let meals`,  basically when using `useEffect`, your generally doing a multi-render, the first render is often not required, because your waiting for the data from `useEffect`..

Comment: @Keith This works too! If you want to put this as an answer. I will up-Vote it. I do not know which solution is better? yours or Pedro's (initializing the state as an empty array already)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I like to exit the render stage if data is yet to come, no point in going any further as the `setState` inside the `useEffect` is going to cause another render anyway.

```
if (!menuData) return null;
let meals = [...new Set(menuData.map((item: menuItem) => item.Meal))];
```

`null` is just a simple way to render nothing..

What I like about this way of doing it, if you find `useEffect` can sometimes take some time, instead of returning `null`, we can maybe return some form of loading indicator..

```
if (!menuData) return <div className="loading">Loading..</div>;
let meals = [...new Set(menuData.map((item: menuItem) => item.Meal))];
```

Initialising the data to something empty works, but you kind of loose some implicit state, and if the structures your rendering are more complex, exiting early I find much easier to reason with..

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. For my purpose, initializing the data to an empty Array suits. However, I am accepting your answer for the detailed explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just initialize your state as an empty array already.

```
const [menuData, setMenuData] = useState<menuData>([]);
```

That should work!